# I have a automod setup but when i try to mention the user when they have triggered the event, i get a ctx error and it says that author is not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code below. How do i define ctx here? This is the error that i get, NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()

    curseWord = [insert bad words here]
    author = message.author.id

    if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
      await message.delete()
      embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description=f"Hey {ctx.author.name} Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: It does not work because you try to use `ctx.author.name` in a `message` event. Simply get the author of the message (`message.author.name`).
`ctx` can't be used in any case, you have to use `message`.

Comment: @Dominik Ok thanks, so then to send the embed, would it be `await message.send(embed=embed)`?

Comment: `message.channel.send(embed=embed)` can be used to send it to the channel.

Comment: Thanks lol, i forgot about channel. Im so used to using `await ctx.send` lol

Comment: `ctx.send` can only be used for `commands` ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use it

```py
async def on_message(ctx: discord.ext.commands.Context, message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()

    curseWord = [insert bad words here]
    author = message.author.id

    if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
      await message.delete()
      embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description=f"Hey {ctx.author.name} Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      await bot.process_commands(message)
```